# How to render a background-image in a PDF document using CSS

Tags: css, pdf-generation, background-image

I have a pdf document generated by my web app. I want to style it using CSS by adding a background image. The dimensions of the image are **250 by 130 px**. The problem is that the **background image appears blurry** when the page is rendered on the browser. Please assist?

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-image: url('img/logo.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 250px;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: As a rule, we cannot help you if you don't replicate your problem in your question. Also, what are the native dimensions of the image ?

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks,, Please check the question, I have updated the dimensions of the image

Comment: From the code you provided we ( at least I ) cannot give you a solution. Can you replicate your problem in a StackOverflow snippet ?

Comment: @MihaiT   Ok,, How do I do that,, am a newbie in Stack overflow

Comment: Visit this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve